# Formatting JSON File Python

Tags: python, json

I am using the code below to dump a dictionary to a JSON file.

```
    for i in result_set:
                d = collections.OrderedDict()
                d["id"]=i["id"]#id
                d["name"]=i["name"]#name
                json_data.append(d)
        result_json=json.dumps(json_data,indent=None)
        return result_json
```

the output of the file is as below

```
[{"id": "A", "name": "A Only"}, {"id": "B", "name": "B Only"} ]
```

how can i get the output in the format as below..

```
[{"id":"A","name":"A Only"},
{"id":"A","name":"B Only"}]
```

I have tried different indent values, with None, Negative and positive integers but it does not seem to work..

Any idea  ??

Comment: I did , and it would just append the \n to the  value like "B Only\n"}

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: Load the json into a string (`x`) and do the following:

```
x = '[{"id": "A", "name": "A Only"}, {"id": "B", "name": "B Only"} ]'
x = '},\n'.join(x.split('},'))
print(x)
```

Comment: this wouldn't give expected result in case of nested dict. ex. `[{"id": "A", "names": {"a": "b}, {"c": "d"}}]`

Comment: @rv.kvetch True, which is why I called it the quick and dirty solution. It works on the sample provided

Comment: You could also use `replace` also instead of `split` and `join`: `x.replace('},', '},\n')`

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to always format a list to JSON and you want to control the output to have newlines in specific places you may need to call `json.dumps` on invidual lines like this:

```
lines = (json.dumps(line) for line in json_data)
joined = ',\n'.join(lines)
result_json = f"[{joined}]"
```